# WordPress not running in local environment, developed for Google app engine

Tags: php, python, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have installed the WordPress, MySQL,PHP SDK on Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) and configure everything according to [google-appengine-help-page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress)

But, I can't access the wordpress in local environment also after the deployment.

when I run the following, in the terminal, from my home directory, where APPLICATION_DIRECTORY IS prsent

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py APPLICATION_DIRECTORY
```

I get error , the output is....

```
INFO     2014-04-14 05:55:59,407 sdk_update_checker.py:242] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2014-04-14 05:56:00,904 sdk_update_checker.py:258] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
INFO     2014-04-14 05:56:00,927 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:44134
INFO     2014-04-14 05:56:00,952 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
ERROR    2014-04-14 05:56:00,953 php_runtime.py:223] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hkc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 219, in new_instance
    self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "/home/hkc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 148, in _check_environment
    'flag (%s) does not exist.' % php_executable_path)
_PHPBinaryError: The path specified with the --php_executable_path flag () does not exist.
INFO     2014-04-14 05:56:00,954 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

The error shows that php_executable_path does not exist. I have the php-5.4.25, google-appengine, APPLICATION_DIRECTORY all under my, home directory.

When I open localhost:8080 (added http:// before that), it shows,

```
The path specified with the --php_executable_path flag () does not exist.
```

How can I correct this ?

Comment: What did you set the `--php_executable_path` command line argument too  and does that match the path to the php executable ?

Comment: @TimHoffman which path should I use here ??

Comment: I don't know (I also don't use php), where did you install PHP, you need to find the path to the executable.

Comment: @TimHoffman, I have installed the php in the home directory in /home/hkc/php-5.4.25 , when I use this path above there, It shows syntax error.

Comment: I believe the path needs to include the php exececutable as well.  as in `--php_executable_path /home/hkc/php-5.4.25/<name_of_php_executable>`

Comment: @TimHoffman can you clear your point, do you know this answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--php_executable_path` should point to a php-cgi installed with Ubuntu. This is likely somewhere like `/usr/bin/php5-cgi`

Comment: I have solved that, But It is now showing Data Base Error. It is showing this error with Wordpress-3.8.2. But it is OK with Wordpress-3.5.1 as listed in the google tutorial. How can I do this for 3.8.2 ??